# Bigquery Backend error

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm getting a "Backend Error" message on a query that works on another set of shards:
eg:

```
select mycols from [2011_Q1],[2011_Q2],[2011_Q3],[2011_Q4] works fine

select mycols from [2012_Q1],[2012_Q2],[2012_Q3] throws backend error.
```

How to debug, or otherwise resolve?

Comment: Can you include a job id of a failed query or your project id?

Comment: job_e64cd6013ebd447ba438c06af0ddc0ef

Answer (score 0):

Your query hit a bug in our query engine. It should work now (or, actually, may give you a results-too-large error because you are grouping by so many fields). If you are hitting the results too large error, try using GROUP EACH BY instead of group by.

Comment: Note this bug should be fixed now.